# TypeError: PlaintextCorpusReader.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fileids'

Tags: google-colaboratory, nltk

I'm trying to use the NLTK's PlaintextCorpusReader in Google Colab to read a corpus. I'm practicing now, so my corpus is just one file.

I mount Google lab, then read

```
import google.colab.drive
google.colab.drive.mount("/content/drive/")
import nltk

# Download punkt package
nltk.download("punkt")

from nltk.corpus.reader.plaintext import PlaintextCorpusReader

# Read the file into a corpus. The same commad could be used to read and entire directory
corpus = PlaintextCorpusReader("[the path to my one-file corpus]")

print(corpus.raw())
```

And I get the following error:

```
TypeError: PlaintextCorpusReader.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fileids'
```

Can anyone help me figure this out?